# tail of youngest files

Tags: bash, tail

How do I run `tail -n 1 -q` on the files which are older than `Apr 1` in this directory?

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 1,6M Mar 31 15:09 1-3-uco-opt-Q7W-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-008.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 1,4M Mar 31 15:10 1-3-uco-opt-Q7W-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-010.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 1,4M Mar 31 15:10 1-3-uco-opt-Q7W-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-011.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 1,6M Apr  1 09:50 1-3-uco-opt-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-002.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 1,6M Apr  2 03:12 1-3-uco-opt-Q7W-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-009.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 465K Apr  2 14:23 1-3-uco-opt-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-000.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 470K Apr  2 14:24 1-3-uco-opt-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-003.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 468K Apr  2 14:24 1-3-uco-opt-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-006.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 465K Apr  2 14:24 1-3-uco-opt-Q7W-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-005.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 466K Apr  2 14:24 1-3-uco-opt-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-005.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 mzhsteno kemi 468K Apr  2 14:24 1-3-uco-opt-Q7W-Q127W-pm6-1.0-15-001.out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` and then exec a `tail`:

```
find /your/dir -mtime +2 -exec tail -n 1 -q {} \;
```

or

```
find /your/dir ! -newermt "20130331 2359:00" -exec tail -n 1 -q {} \;
```

Comment: ok. and then `tail -n 1 -q ` will operate on all files that `find` identifies?

Comment: Yes. It should. Please try and indicate it, so I can update answer if it fails.